# Sitecom 300N port forwarding access from lan

Tags: networking, router, dns, lan, port-forwarding

I have this modem-router:

- external IP: `x.x.x.x` (static)
- internal IP: `192.168.0.1`

now, I have assigned `x.x.x.x` as `www.mydomain.com`, `app.mydomain.com` and `svn.mydomain.com` on public DNS.

on the LAN (NAT) I have my server with internal IP `192.168.0.150`. The server has apache2 with some virtual host configured that match DNS records.

I mapped a port forward for port 80.

Accessing `*.mydomain.com` from outside the LAN works good, forward happens and I can see my server.

The problem is when I try to access `*.mydomain.com` from a LAN client: port forward does not happen and I see the router admin page!

Note that:

- I cannot a access `http://192.168.0.150` because of virtual hosts configuration, and however, I like to preserve the same name address for internal and external
- This piece of junk can only forward to the same port (forward `x.x.x.x:8080` to `192.168.0.150:80` can't be configured...)
- I haven't found a way to configure DNS records on the router

Any idea?

Maybe putting an internal DNS server will solve?

---

@DavidPostill

no it can't be done, just like I said:

> - This piece of junk can only forward to the same port (forward `x.x.x.x:8080` to `192.168.0.150:80` can't be configured...)

[image: virtual server listing]

`start port` and `end port` are used to define a **port range**, don't confuse with `source port` and `destination port`, in this piece of junk there's no such thing.

Comment: Your router needs to support NAT forwarding, which it does not if this isn't working.  So yes, an internal DNS server would solve the problem, or updating your local hosts file

Answer (score 1):

Edit your [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file and add the following:

```
192.168.0.150 www.mydomain.com
192.168.0.150 app.mydomain.com
192.168.0.150 svn.mydomain.com
```

Comment: Thanks, but configuring hosts file on every single client is not doable. I thought there could be a "router trick" for doing this.

Comment: The router is a Wireless Range Extender. Can you configure the **upstream** router?

Comment: No, it's not an extender. It's a ADSL2+ modem-router.

Comment: Then please give the rest of the model number as there seem to be different kinds of Sitecom 300N router - does it have a WLXXX number as well?

Comment: WLM-3500 v2001, firmware 1.07

Comment: forward x.x.x.x:8080 to 192.168.0.150:80 can be configured. Use the Virtual Server function when you want different servers/clients inyour LAN to handle different service/Internet application type (e.g. Email, FTP, Web server etc.) from the Internet. The Virtual Server allows you to re-direct a particular service port number (from the Internet/WAN Port) to a particular LAN private IP address and its service port number. Your router supports Virtual servers, see the user manual.

Comment: see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

i setted up my own DNS server on `192.168.0.150` and made the router use and propagate it:

[image: dns]

now everything is working fine.